# How can display the lines from linux log file in browser

Tags: python, linux, django

I am getting the lines from the `linux` log files and i am displaying in the bowser using django.

1. They are all displaying as same paragarah but i want to show them with new lines
2. They display in nelwines if i warp them in `<pre> lines </pre>` but then my html tags are not rendered properly

is there any way to display that in good format with newlines and html tag rendered properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in template tags:

```
{{ lines|linebreaks }}
```

or

```
{{ lines|linebreaksbr }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `linebreaks` or `linebreakbr` filters. From [django reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks)

```
linebreaks
Replaces line breaks in plain text with appropriate HTML; a single newline becomes an 
HTML line break (<br />) and a new line followed by a blank line becomes a paragraph 
break (</p>).
```

For example:

```
{{ value|linebreaks }}
  If value is Joel\nis a slug, the output will be <p>Joel<br />is a slug</p>.
```

You can also use `linenumbers`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert newlines to `<br />` tags

There is a Django filter that can be useful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks

```
{{ value|linebreaks }}
```